# Should I use ToString() or GetDateTimeFormats() to format a DateTime?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, formatting, string-formatting

I know how to format a `DateTime` as a `String`. There may be many ways to format a `DateTime` as a `String`, and I have found few questions related to `DateTime` formatting.

But I found and tried two ways:

1. `GetDateTimeFormats()`
2. `ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`

I tried this code:

```
public static class DateTimeFormates
{
    public static string FormatMyDate(this DateTime DT)
    {
        // My Actual Date Time Comes in this Format
        //8/23/2013 12:43:12 PM

        // I'm expecting Format like below

        String FormatWayOne = DT.GetDateTimeFormats()[3];
        //08/23/2013

        String FormatWayTwo = DT.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        //08/23/2013

        return FormatWayOne;
    }
}
```

I have a `Global` class with `Global` method to format a `DateTime` as a `String`. But here what I want to know which method is the best practice so I can use it? The method is called all over the application.

Comment: FYI `DateTime` doesn't have any format. It is stored as `Long(Ticks)`. String representation of `DateTime` only owns format

Comment: +1 strange, never heard of `DateTime.GetDateTimeFormats`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`GetDateTimeFormats` is not a replacement for `ToString` and vice versa. If you know what format you want, there's no need to call `GetDateTimeFormats`. As well as it being clearer to use `ToString`, the [document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyk2998w.aspx) for `GetDateTimeFormats` states this (emphasis mine)

> Because this method uses culture-sensitive data, **you should not assume
>   that multiple calls to the method will return identical data**. The data
>   returned by this method can change if the current culture changes, the
>   user overrides individual cultural settings, or an update occurs to
>   the system's cultural data.

This could potentially break your code as the third element could be something else when run in another culture.

By using ToString, you're avoiding having to loop through all date formats (hence being more efficient) and you're making it clearer as to what format you like whilst ensuring that the format returned is the one you want.

Comment: true. if you know what you want - call it. No need to fetch with bucket and then selecting it.

Answer (score 8):

ToString is clearer, and also it doesn't use a magic number that might not work in the next framework version/another culture. Use `ToString()`.

Answer (score 5):

> Which one is Good Practice or Best way

Both are good for their own needs.

> difference between this two ways?

**[GetDateTimeFormats()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyk2998w.aspx)**

Converts the value of this instance to all the string representations supported by the standard date and time format specifiers. Which means it is an expensive operation and getting the third element each time may give you different results. You don't need to convert to all formats so why do so?

**[ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx)**

Converts the value of the current DateTime object to its equivalent string representation using the specified format.

> Any Suggestions or Ideas?

As Second method (ToString) is only converting to your required format and is more readable as well. Hence preferrable. Whereas, if you use the first method you will be converting to around 100 formats when you require only one.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer `ToString(format)` version only. but not the format you shown as example. It can screw you across the culture.
Let's take a look at following example.

```
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

    string fmt1 = now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); // MM/dd/yyyy
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-us")
    { 
        DateTimeFormat=
        {
            DateSeparator = "-"
        }
    };
    string fmt1a = now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); // MM-dd-yyyy (you're in trouble when you want to deserialize)

    string fmt2 = now.ToString("MMddyyyy"); // MMddyyyy
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-us")
    {
        DateTimeFormat =
        {
            DateSeparator = "-"
        }
    };
    string fmt2a = now.ToString("MMddyyyy"); and // MMddyyyy always
```

Am not going to talk about `GetDateTimeFormats` here since it is a overkill.

Wondering how `fmt1a` can return `MM-dd-yyyy` when you say `MM/dd/yyyy` ? because `/` is a special character which is used to represent `DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeperator` of current culture.

So, I'll suggest you to use custom formatting without `/` for serialization and any other formatting for UI.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using .ToString(format) for years, and it's never let me down. You can use built in formats, or customize your own.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the date and as I see, the culture format is correct, just use the datetime method ToShortDateString

```
MyDateTime.ToShortDateString();
```

But using this in an extesion method doesn't make any sense. If you want to convert any date in any format to always display in MM/dd/yyyy you should first set then culture and the call the method.

Check here for the proper code to use http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx

Comment: Ya I agree this is also one way.,

Comment: Edited to fix some misspelling